# How can I be considered bloodied while above half HP?

Tags: dnd-4e

Is there any consistent way for a character to count as bloodied for bonuses such as Vampire regeneration and Dragonborn attack boosts?

Comment: Are you asking for ways to be bloodied without being below half hit points?

Comment: that's the way I interpret it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way is to *be bloodied.*

Granted this is also the most dangerous way, but it's the simplest.

However, you appear to be (Based on your question), to be looking for a way to count as bloodied without actually *being* bloodied.

There are several weapons that allow you to do this in various ways though:

- [Blood Fury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=691) weapon, which has an encounter power that does exactly what you want for one turn (ADV2).
- [Battle Crazed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=625) weapon, which allows you to deal damage to yourself and be bloodied for a turn (ADV)
- [Flensing Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1317), which allows you to *inflict* bloodied as a condition as part of an attack as a daily power (Dragon 368)

There really isn't a way for you to get this easily for more than a couple of turns, as it's a pretty powerful tool to be considered bloodied, but not actually be.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, yes. Are you sure Infernal Eye can make you count as bloodied? It has an augmentable attack that makes an enemy count as bloodied, but I don't see anything else.

Comment: @BobWatkins yeah, looks like I misread it, removing.