# Ways to count as bloodied earlier

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions

Are there any feats, items, even powers that will make it so that you count as bloodied being over 1/2 HP?

I ask because I have a couple of characters who have abilities that would be useful to have active before being under 1/2 HP, so by counting as bloodied at 3/4's would be great.

Comment: Can this question explain how it's different from [this question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60004/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan The titles are completely different, like only 80% of the words match. That also didnt pop up as possible matches when I was making the question...